# Forwarding the checkbox state change to the parent component using callback React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the child component, I change the checkbox state and want to pass the value of this state to the parent component.  Transfer this value to the parental state.  Now my code looks like this. In Teaser component, autocomplete is undefined and the code does not work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFgYb.png)

Comment: you can't pass to the parent component. define it in the parent component and then pass it down as props to use in the child component. please don't photo code too, show RELEVANT code in the question

Comment: Please share the code snippet instead of an image of it

Answer (score 2):

`setSwitchValue` don't return any value. so nothing is passed back to callback and like @DanneManne mentioned you have one typo mistake.

Comment: Now I refactor my code just like the pictures below and it still doesn't work

Comment: you are saving value of function which don't return anything. 
eg: val = someStateHook(); then u doing callback(val) which sent wrong value to parent 
do something like: onValueChanged(!switchValue)

Answer (score 1):

The callback chain looks right, but it also looks like you are using the wrong variable in Teaser on line 13. I assume it should check the value of  `autocompleteData` and not `autoComplete` (which is a function).

Comment: Now I refactor my code just like the pictures below and it still doesn't work